# Restore default UITableViewCell backgroundView

Tags: ios, uitableview

**In short**, I need to restore the default `backgroundView` for a `UITableViewStyleGrouped` cell.

```
cell.backgroundView = ??;
```

---

**The long story**: 
I have a grouped tableview with some cells. For every cell the user needs to select some value or do some input. After that he can proceed to the next ViewController by touching a "next" button.

Anyway, to indicate to the user that he missed something, I display a nice red border around the cell with the wrong/missing user input. I do that by setting the `backgroudView` of the cell with a custom image like this:

```
cell.backgroundView = myErrorIndicatingImageView;
```

The cell now looks like this (screenshot, ignore the stars and label)
[image]

So far so good, this works like a charm. But after the user corrects the input I want to remove my red border background image and just show the original background again. The original background looks like this (screenshot):
[image]

And this seems to be a problem.

I tried several things

```
// try by setting the background to nil
cell.backgroundView = nil;
```

this removes the background completely and I'm lost with a cell without background.

```
// try it with addSubview and later remove the subview again
[cell.backgroundView addSubview:myErrorIndicatingImageView];
```

this does nothing. The `myErrorIndicatingImageView` is not visible. Even a `[cell.backgroundView bringSubviewToFront:myErrorIndicatingImageView]` does not help.

Right now the only solution I have is to create a new `UITableViewCell` for every single call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. This works but is just bad code and ignores completely the technique to reuse cells.

There must be a simpler solution...something like

```
cell.backgroundView = [self.tableView getDefaultBackgroundView];
```

Answer (score 0):

what about trying this:

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.backgroundView.frame];
```

Or you can make the background view as a `UIImageView` and set 2 images in problem and fixed

Comment: `cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.backgroundView.frame];` has the same effect as setting the `backgroundView = nil;`. It removes the background completely. Using two UIImageViews would be a solution, but why recreate the default background, if the system already knows how to draw it perfectly?

Comment: what is the default background looks like? . Also did u try to reload the table view after sitting the new `backgroundView` with nil or `UIView alloc init` , it may solve the problem

Comment: I added some screenshots to the original question. All my logic is already in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. So `cellForRowAtIndexPath` decides which background to draw. If my helper methods want to change the background they call `[self.tableView reloadData]`. So the problem is if `cellForRowAtIndexPath` already created the cell before and I reuse that cell with `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` then it seems not possible to set the original background to a cell who has the error background set.

Comment: i think the best thing to have 2 versions of `myErrorIndicatingImageView` one with red background and one without, and in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add one of them as you need

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are doing this with a custom table cell class, save the original `backgroundView` in some ivar, then apply the new background. When you want to reset the background, set the `backgroundView` back to the original, saved background view.